# dyndns.org update via php/curl?

Tags: curl, dyndns

Im attempting to maintain an account at dyndns.org via php/curl. Im using (per RTFM):

```
 https://$account:$pw@members.dyndns.org/nic/update?hostname=$host&myip=$ip
```

but I get a 'nohost' response if $host is new. If $host is an existing entry it works.

Has anyone used this method of communicating with dyndns?
Is the api only used to update existing entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only send IP address updates to existing DynDNS hostnames with the DynDNS API, you cannot create new hostnames.

If you need a full API for creating/deleting/changing hostnames, Dynect SMB may interest you:
http://www.dyndns.com/services/dynectsmb/

Comment: I got an email from dyndns that made it sound more like we had too many entries in our zone. Still trying to figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

Since this question was asked three years ago, I can confirm that this still works (in terms of: it just [updates an existing hostname](http://dyn.com/support/developers/api/perform-update/)) with

```
curl "https://test:test@members.dyndns.org/nic/update?hostname=test.dyndns.org&myip=1.2.3.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

As Oracle have started charging for DynDNS it means the mac client no longer works on 10.15 and higher. I wrote a simple shell script to do this

```
#!/bin/shell
IP=$(curl "checkip.amazonaws.com")
echo $IP
curl "https://username:updaterpassword@members.dyndns.org/v3/update?hostname=biscuit.home.dyndns.org&myip=${IP}"
```

Replace the username and updater password in the above.

Works on Mac OS X and Linux

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it works dyndns with php and curl

```
$server_url = "test.dyndns.biz";
$current_ip ="1.2.3.4";
$url = "https://members.dyndns.org/nic/update?system=dyndns&hostname=".$server_url."&myip=".$current_ip;
                                                              
$username="xxxxxxx";
$password="xxxxxxx";
$base64 = base64_encode("$username:$password");
$authorization = "Authorization: Basic $base64";
$userAgent = "User-Agent: Update Client/v1.0"; 
$headers = array($authorization, $userAgent);     
                                                  
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
```